# Difference between prefix and postfix increment operators overloading implementations for iterators in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list, operator-overloading

I was reading a book on data structures, now trying to implement singly-linked list data structure. While implementing iterators, I have come across these implementations of overloaded prefix and postfix increments:

```
iterator &operator++()
{
    this->current = this->current->next;
    return *this;
}

iterator &operator++(int)
{
    iterator old = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return old;
}
```

I know that the first one is for prefix and the second one is for postfix, but what I haven't understand is why does overloaded postfix increment have different code? What would be wrong if I do this?

```
iterator &operator++(int)
{
    this->current = this->current->next;
    return *this;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, both postfix versions are wrong. **The postfix iterator must return a copy, not a reference.**

The point is that post-increment changes the incremented object, but returns a version of it before the increment. The pre-increment changes the object and returns the incremented version. Their logic must differ accordingly.

This distinction is made because post- and pre-increment have the same semantics on primitive types. Example:

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
```

yields the output 0. Your class with overloaded iterators should imitate that behaviour for consistency. If you had your own integer class with one of the iterator implementations you've shown, the result would be 1, and thereby surprising.

The correct implementation of a postfix increment is in 99% of the cases:

```
iterator operator++(int)
{
    iterator old = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return old;
}
```

Comment: i thought that the first one is returning a copy

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: No, note the '&' in the declaration ("iterator &operator++"). It is returning a reference to a local variable, thereby having undefined behaviour.

Comment: by the way, is it correct that the prefix one is returning a reference or should it also return a copy?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: Yes, it should absolutely return a reference.